# Strange behavior when executing remote commands with nested SSH

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I encountered a strange problem when using ssh to execute commands on a remote host. Assuming `hostname` returns hostA on hostA, `hostname` returns hostB on hostB, and so on. Guess what the following command will return?

```bash
ssh -A -t userA@hostA ssh -A -tt userB@hostB "hostname;hostname;hostname"
```

I originally thought it would be:

```
hostB
hostB
hostB
```

But the actual result is:

```
hostB
Connection to hostB closed.
hostA
hostA
```

An even more complex example is:

```bash
ssh -A -t userA@hostA ssh -A -t userB@hostB ssh -A -tt userC@hostC \
    "hostname \''&&'\' hostname '&&' hostname '&&' hostname && hostname && hostname"
```

And it actually returns:

```
hostC
hostC
Connection to hostC closed.
hostB
hostB
Connection to hostB closed.
hostA
hostA
Connection to hostA closed.
```

I want to know how the above commands are parsed or interpreted by the shell or SSH. Can someone explain step by step how the commands are executed?

Comment: Everything you pass to ssh as a positional argument gets concatenated together into a single string, and that single string is passed to a shell. A space that's contained _within_ an argument and a space created by the act of joining arguments have exactly the same priority; it has all the same bugs as a script containing only `eval "$*"` or `sh -c "$*"`.

Comment: This all becomes very obvious when you look at the wire protocol spec, which only passes a single string over the wire as the command to run, instead of passing an argument vector. Because there's no argument vector, the protocol _can't_ represent an arbitrary argv unless it's escaped in a manner appropriate to the remote shell.

Comment: ...this is all to say, chepner's answer is completely correct and on-point, including in particular the advice to only ever pass `ssh` a single positional argument comprising a single command already correctly escaped for the remote shell to parse.

Comment: That said, think about `cmd=( ssh -A -tt userB@hostB "hostname;hostname;hostname" ); ssh -A -t userA@hostA "${cmd[*]@Q}"` if you only need support for bash 5.0+

Answer (score 2):

The shell on host A executes the following command:

```
 ssh -A -tt userB@hostB hostname;hostname;hostname
```

not

```
 ssh -A -tt userB@hostB "hostname;hostname;hostname"
```

As such, only the *first* `hostname` is an argument to `ssh`. The semicolon terminates that command so that the following `hostname` commands are "peers" of `ssh`, not arguments of `ssh`.

The process of joining multiple command arguments into a single command is not straightforward, and I generally recommend passing a single string argument yourself.

```
ssh -A -t userA@hostA 'ssh -A -tt userB@hostB "hostname;hostname;hostname"'
```